# is it a kind of koenig look up?

Tags: c++

According to the article posted at http://wikistack.com/koenig-lookup-or-argument-dependent-lookup/ 
koenig look happens only in case of namespace. if it is true then how lookup happens in below case

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    friend void hello(foo obj) {
        cout << "hello\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    foo foo_obj;
    hello(foo_obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that ADL is also applicable for class templates, not only namespaces, see example: [https://godbolt.org/z/rmYDXq](https://godbolt.org/z/rmYDXq). Though the case in the question is not ADL.

Answer (score 1):

Making `hello` a `friend` of `foo` means that it's *not* actually a member of `foo` (despite its definition being inside of `foo`'s definition). Its definition is "injected" into the surrounding namespace (the global namespace in this case).

This creates an otherwise rather unusual situation, in which the function is defined in a particular namespace, but is not declared in that namespace. That being the case, nearly the only way for it to be invoked is for its name to be found via argument dependent lookup (ADL, aka Koenig lookup).