# Question about Friend functions used in C++

Tags: c++, oop, declaration, public, friend

I am working with a C++ class that includes a friend function for calculations. However, I noticed that even though the friend function is declared within the class, it seems to work without being defined inside the class body.
The program runs successfully, and the friend function is able to access the private member data of the class. Why does this work, and is it considered good practice to define the friend function outside the class in this way? I'm confused about the role of friend functions and whether they need to be defined within the class body.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass {
private:
    int data;

public:
    MyClass(int d) {
        data = d;
    };
    friend void myFriendFunction(MyClass& obj);
};
void myFriendFunction(MyClass& obj) {
    cout << "Friend function accessing private data: " << obj.data << endl;
}

int main() {
    MyClass myObject(42);
    myFriendFunction(myObject);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Why does this work" Well, because the C++ standard says it should. Why do you believe it shouldn't have worked?

Comment: friendship means that something what do not belong to class has privilege to have access to private parts of class. That it. So I do not understand your confusion `myFriendFunction` do not belong to `MyClass` scope. I never use this keyword.

Comment: The confusion might be that the `friend` function actually belongs to the namespace scope, not the class scope, regardless of whether or not it is defined in the class. The weird case is actually that you can _define_ the function in the class scope although it doesn't belong to it. Fundamentally the `friend` declaration just declares that the named function from the enclosing namespace shall be a `friend` of the class, but there are special rules in the language that allow you to define the named function into the enclosing namespace scope at the same time.

Comment: And furthermore, there are special lookup rules for functions in case they are only declared/defined in the class scope (as `friend`) but not in the enclosing namespace scope (although they belong to it). Namely, such functions can only be found by argument-dependent lookup, but not usual unqualified lookup.

Comment: [When you declare a friend function with an unqualified id in a class it names a function in the nearest enclosing namespace scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284809/12002570)

Answer (score 0):

Declaring function as a friend inside of class is enough. Class has to confirm that function that is trying to access it's private members is a friend of this class and therefore has right to do it. That is what's happening in your code.

As far as i know friend function should be defined outside of class body. If you define it inside then why won't make it a method of this class?

Comment: A `friend` can't be a member of the class, so `class foo { friend int bar() {} };` means `bar` is a friend of `foo` that's a defined in the namespace surrounding `foo`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584859/179910